# Inserting data to database using foreachloop

Tags: c#

## I am using a foreach loop

```
foreach(var x in items)
{
    // enter code here
}
```

and in my code i am sending data to database suppose in my `items` list i have 10 records i am sending to database  after sending of 5 records due to some problem sending data failed how to rollback all the data i sent to `database`.

is there any way to handle this situation--i am using entity data model

Comment: what classes do you use in your database operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to rollback all the data i sent to database.

Use Transactions with your insertion commands. If your targeting database is SQL Server then you cause [SqlTransaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.aspx) with `try/catch` block, so that if an exception occurs you can `Rollback` the transaction.

An example from the MSDN

```
private static void ExecuteSqlTransaction(string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        SqlTransaction transaction;

        // Start a local transaction.
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");

        // Must assign both transaction object and connection 
        // to Command object for a pending local transaction
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Transaction = transaction;

        try
        {
            command.CommandText =
                "Insert into Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) VALUES (100, 'Description')";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.CommandText =
                "Insert into Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) VALUES (101, 'Description')";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Attempt to commit the transaction.
            transaction.Commit();
            Console.WriteLine("Both records are written to database.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Commit Exception Type: {0}", ex.GetType());
            Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex.Message);

            // Attempt to roll back the transaction. 
            try
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                // This catch block will handle any errors that may have occurred 
                // on the server that would cause the rollback to fail, such as 
                // a closed connection.
                Console.WriteLine("Rollback Exception Type: {0}", ex2.GetType());
                Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex2.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```